# apex query optimization

Tags: apex, query

I have this query (somewhat striped down for brevity) where the bind variable of ids is "Set ids" from a trigger.  What I want to do to is get the data for all the ids from the trigger and where the ID exists in the custom object Company_Contact_Relation where the related company type is a member.

My background is more PL/SQL but base on what I can discern this seems to be the best way to structure the query.  I wanted to reach out to the community to see if they agree with the query or have a better way.

```
SELECT
id,
Recordtype.DeveloperName
FROM
contact
WHERE
ID IN :ids
AND
ID IN (SELECT Contact__c FROM Company_Contact_Relation__c WHERE Company__r.Type = 'Member')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a perfectly fine query. The ID clause will make the query selective, and the remaining clause will filter that list down to just contacts that meet the additional criteria of being a 'Member'.